Problem with DateOnly format when passing a value to a SQL Server stored procedure
I am trying to get this working, but it fails with the following error when I try to fill my dataset (it's an Azure SQL database, and the client is on .NET 7.0):

No mapping exists from object type System.DateOnly to a known managed provider native type.

My stored procedure is:
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_WMSSummaryStats]
    @userId INT,
    @datefrom date,
    @dateto date
AS
   .....

My Web API endpoint looks like this:
[HttpGet("homePageSummaryData")]
public string homePageSummaryData(int user, int warehouseId, int zoneId, DateOnly startDate, DateOnly endDate, string licenseKey)
{
    // ....
}

I call the stored procedure from the Web API code like this:
cmd.Connection = conn;

conn.Open();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", user);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datefrom" , startDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateto", endDate);

I have tried to test the end point in Swagger, but it's generating the same error.

That error means you need to update your Microsoft.Data.SqlClient reference: https://erikej.github.io/dotnet/sqlclient/2022/11/17/sqlclient-dateonly.html

Don't use .AddWithValue(). Use SqlParameter.Add(String, SqlDbType). cmd.Parameters.Add("@datefrom", SqlDbType.Date).Value = startDate;

@YongShun Why doesn't Microsoft slap [Obsolete] on AddWithValue? It's maddening...

"the client is on .NET 7.0" - PSA that .NET 7.0 went out of support in May 2024. I know it's not what the question is about, but it's worth being proactive about updating to .NET 8.

Since version 5.1.0 the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient NuGet package does support DateOnly and TimeOnly as value-types for use with SqlParameter.Value and elsewhere.
...so you'll only get the "No mapping exists from object type System.DateOnly to a known managed provider native type." error if you're using an outdated version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.
As of June 2024, the current version is 5.2.1, and v5.1.0 has been out for almost 18 months now.
